# Creating a new page for each submission - PHP errors

Tags: php, mysql, html

[Here](http://www.ewsprojects.com/~lyons) is the site.

I have the submit page, and a form action to a page that queries the submission info into my database. I'll include that code below. What I want to do, is have it create an individual page for each submission. However, I'm getting tons of errors when I try to upload. It uploads but it definitely doesn't create new page. the  I have a template form which I'll show you, but first, here's the upload page:

```
<?php
// For use in creating individual page
$tpl_file = "submission.php";
$tpl_path = "/~lyons/templates/";
$submissions_path = "/~lyons/submissions";


// For use in querying submitter name

$username = $_GET['username'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username; 

//Database Information

$dbhost = "";
$dbname = "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";

//Connect to database

mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());


$name = $_POST['name'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];   
$submitter = $username;
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("$filename");
$type = exif_imagetype($_POST['filename']);

$checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM images WHERE filename='$filename'");

$filename_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkuser);

if($filename_exist > 0){
    echo "I'm sorry but this image has already been submitted. Please feel free to try another.";
    unset($filename);
    include 'upload.php';
    exit();
}


if (exif_imagetype($_POST['filename']) == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo "Sorry, but we can't accept GIFs. Please feel free to try uploading another.";
    unset($filename);
    include 'upload.php';
    exit();
}



$query = "INSERT INTO images (name, filename, submitter, width, height, type)
VALUES('$name', '$filename', '$submitter', '$width', '$height', $type)";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

echo "Thanks for your submission!<br/> Upload another <a href='/~lyons/upload.php'>here</a>!";

$placeholders = array("{name}", "{filename}", "{username}");
$tpl = file_get_contents($tpl_path.$tpl_file);
$new_member_file = str_replace($placeholders, $data, $tpl);
$php_file_name = $username.".php";

$fp = fopen($submissions_path.$php_file_name, "w");
fwrite($fp, $new_submission_file);
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

And here's the template file (submission.php)

```
<html>
<title>{name}</title>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h1>{name}</h1>
Posted by: {username}
<br/>
<img src="{filename}"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the errors you are getting?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(/~lyons/templates/submission.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/lyons/public_html/uploadimages.php on line 62



Warning: fopen(/~lyons/submissions.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/lyons/public_html/uploadimages.php on line 66


Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/lyons/public_html/uploadimages.php on line 68

Comment: Where does submission.php live, relative to uploadimages.php ?

Comment: uploadimages.php is right in public_html, whereas submission.php is inside a folder called 'templates' (which is inside public_html)

Comment: It may be a path issue.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have a path issue.  When you use the path "/~lyons" you may not be pointing to the directory you want.  Try making the changes below:

```
// For use in creating individual page
$tpl_file = "submission.php";
//$tpl_path = "/~lyons/templates/";
$tpl_path = "templates/";
```

And then please post the new error message(s), if any.

Comment: Here's what I changed everything to:
 
    `$tpl_file = "submission.php";
    $tpl_path = "templates/";
    $submissions_path = "submissions/";`

And it doesn't give me any errors anymore, but it still doesn't create the page in submissions. Any ideas? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I think we can be sure that it was a path issue; you were not pointing to relative paths, so the files did not actually exist.  Now, I would wonder about permissions.  Are you sure that your script can read and write to the directories that you're dealing with?

Comment: If you are on a *nix system, use `ls -la` and you will see the permissions on the left-hand side.  The format is `drwxrwxrwx` and a minus sign `-` may appear in any of those columns.  The `d` signifies "directory" ( a `-` here means this item is not a directory ), while the `rwx`'s stand for "read", "write", and "execute" permissions. They are grouped into three sets, with the first corresponding to the owner (user) permissions, the second set to the owner group, and the third set to everyone else.  [`chmod`](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml) is used to change permissions on *nix.

Comment: If you are on a Windows or Mac system, you can right-click on the directory in question and view its Properties or Info.

What we're looking for is to confirm that the script can read and write to these directories.  The short answer may be just to go to .../public_html/ and, from there, issue a `chmod 777 ./submissions` and a `chmod 777 ./templates`... but that's certainly not elegant.

Comment: I just noticed, when I submit a picture, it adds a file to the submissions folder called just '.php' without anything else. File contains nothing when I open, but it does take the php extension I gave it in #php_file_name. Mean anything? Only does it once though. If I upload another it doesn't add another file there, but it does it again if I delete the file first.

Comment: Did you mean to use `$filename` here instead of `$username`:  `$php_file_name = $username.".php";`?  Also, this may be a little late in the game to bring this up, but why don't you use a single page (`file.php` for instance) and load the desired file via GET? **ALSO**, did you mean to use `$new_member_file` instead of `$new_submission_file` here: `fwrite($fp, $new_submission_file);`?

Comment: I put in `$name` in place of username (it's the title people give their submitted images), and it works well for the titles. Every image I uploads creates a file with the name and then .php. However, I still can't get it to actually put anything in the file. It's a completely blank file. I'm looking into it but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew. I fixed most of it because of you so I used yours as the accepted answer. Still having one more problem that I posted a new question for because it's dead here, but I definitely appreciate your help.

Comment: @user996494 Thanks for the accept.  I'll check out your new question tomorrow and see what I can do to help.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

To help you in debugging, try turning error reporting and error display on.

```
// add after <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Opening the file is probably failing, for better error control try this:

```
$fp = @fopen($submissions_path.$php_file_name, "w");
if (!$fp) {
    die('Failed to open file!  Reason: ' . $php_errormsg);
}
```

I think your paths are incorrect, most likely the following 2 lines need to be changed to use a full path.

```
// change
$tpl_path = "/~lyons/templates/";
$submissions_path = "/~lyons/submissions";

// to
$tpl_path         = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/~lyons/templates/";
$submissions_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/~lyons/submissions";
```

When you go to open the file, it is trying to open `/~lyons/templates/` which is a directory that does not exist, it is probably something like `/home/lyons/public_html/templates/` or `/home/something/public_html/~lyons/templates` or `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/~lyons/templates` etc.  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should fill in the correct value, but in few cases you may need to manually set the correct path and prepend it to your $tpl_path and $submissions_path.

Comment: Just to prevent the error messages from php from being output to the screen since the error is being handled by the if statement.  Some hosts leave display_errors on in production and if the open fails, it keeps that information from being displayed to the user.

Comment: ugh! aren't you doing the same - echoing an error to the user *unconditionally?*

Comment: and what if the same hoster leave `track_errors` at default 0?

Comment: It's an **example** to show him to handle opening files, I don't expect, or even hope he uses that exact code in production.

Comment: how come you don't expect it if you posted it as an **example**? I can't get your logic. isn't setting 'display_errors' quite enough?

Comment: When I do the third block of code you give me, I get these errors:

Warning: file_get_contents(/home/projects/public_html/~lyons/templates/submission.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/lyons/public_html/uploadimages.php on line 63

Warning: fopen(/home/projects/public_html/~lyons/submissions.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/lyons/public_html/uploadimages.php on line 67

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/lyons/public_html/uploadimages.php on line 69

Comment: Looks like your correct document root is `/home/lyons/public_html/` so try `$tpl_path = '/home/lyons/public_html/templates/` and `$submissions_path = '/home/lyons/public_html/submissions` and make sure the upload directory has the correct permissions, may need to be 777.

Answer (score 0):

```
**save the "submission.php" in root folder**
`$tpl_file = "submission.php";`
**create "templates/`" folder in root folder**
`$tpl_path = "templates/";`
```